# R Shiny: Crosstable and Plot grouping with reactive values

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am building a Shiny app to display variables of the "European Social Survey" (table and graph). Therefore I created conditional panels with "selectInput" where the user can select which variable should be displayed. In a second step I want to group the displayed variable by e.g. gender. For doing so I included a checkbox. If this checkbox is TRUE a further conditional panel shows up where the user can choose the independent variable.
I tried to group the plot by using the `facet_grid` command - without success. Further I tried the generate a very simple crosstable (trying both a `datatable` command with a dataframe and a `table` command; latter in the expample below) - also without success.

Any advice?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(likert)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

levels.netusoft <- c('Sehr wenig', 'Etwas', 'Stark', 'Sehr stark', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.ppltrst <- c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.polintr <- c('Überhaupt nicht', 'Sehr wenig', 'Etwas', 'Stark', 'Sehr stark', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.psppsgva <- c('Überhaupt nicht fähig', 'Wenig fähig', 'Ziemlich fähig', 'Sehr fähig', 'Vollkommen fähig', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.actrolga <- c('Wenig fähig', 'Ziemlich fähig', 'Sehr fähig', 'Vollkommen fähig', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.gndr <- c('männlich', 'weiblich')
dataset <- data.frame('netusoft'=factor(sample(levels.netusoft[1:7], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'ppltrst'=factor(sample(levels.ppltrst[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'polintr'=factor(sample(levels.polintr[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'psppsgva'=factor(sample(levels.psppsgva[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'actrolga'=factor(sample(levels.actrolga[1:7], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'gndr'=factor(sample(levels.gndr[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      check.names=FALSE)


# ----- UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "European Social Survey Österreich Dashboard", titleWidth = 300),
        dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                         selectInput(inputId='round', label="Wählen Sie eine ESS Runde aus",  
                                     c("ESS 1" = "1",
                                       "ESS 2" = "2",
                                       "ESS 3" = "3",
                                       "ESS 4" = "4",
                                       "ESS 5" = "5",
                                       "ESS 7" = "7",
                                       "ESS 8" = "8",
                                       "ESS 9" = "9"),
                                     selected = "9", selectize = FALSE), #end selectinput
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.round == '9'",
                             selectInput(inputId='battery', label="Wählen Sie Themenfeld aus",  
                                         c("A: Medien-, Internetnutzung, Soziales Vertrauen" = "A",
                                           "B: Politische Variablen, Immigration" = "B"), selectize = FALSE), #end selectinput
                         ), #end conditionalPanel
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.round == '9' && input.battery == 'A'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "avA_9", label = "Wählen Sie eine Frage aus", 
                                         c("A2|Häufigkeit Internetnutzung" = "netusoft", 
                                           "A4|Vertrauen in Mitmenschen" = "ppltrst"), selectize = FALSE), #end selectInput
                         ), #end conditionalPanel 
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.round == '9' && input.battery == 'B'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "avB_9", label = "Wählen Sie eine Frage aus", 
                                         c("B1|Interesse an Politik" = "polintr", 
                                           "B2|Politische Mitsprachem?glichkeit" = "psppsgva", 
                                           "B3|Fähigkeit politischen Engagements " = "actrolga"), selectize = FALSE) #end selectInput
                         ), #end conditionalPanel
                         checkboxInput(
                             inputId = "group",
                             label = "Daten gruppieren",
                             value = FALSE), #end checkbox
                         
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.group==true",
                             selectInput(
                                 inputId = "UV",
                                 label = "Daten gruppieren nach:",
                                 c("Geschlecht" = "gndr")
                             ) # end conditionalPanel
                         )
                         
        ), # end dashboardSidebar
        
        dashboardBody(
            
            fluidRow(
                box(width = 7, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    title = "Table:",
                    dataTableOutput("tabelle", width = "100%")
                ),
                box(width = 8, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    title = "Graph:",
                    plotOutput("plot", width = "auto", height = 500)
                )
            ) # end fluidRow
            
        ) #end dashboardBody
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    av.select <- reactive({
        if (input$battery == "A" && input$round == "9") {
            av.select <- input$avA_9
        }
        else if (input$battery == "B" && input$round == "9") {
            av.select <- input$avB_9
        }
        return(av.select)
    })
    
    
    #Plotting the data  
    plot.data <- reactive({
        data <- subset(dataset, select=c(av.select(), input$UV))
        data <- data[complete.cases(data)==1,] %>%
            mutate_all(as_factor) %>%
            droplevels(exclude = c("Weiß nicht", "Verweigert", "Keine Antwort")) %>%
            as.data.frame()
    }) 
    
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot.data.g <- likert(plot.data()[,1, drop=FALSE])
        p <- plot(plot.data.g) 
        
        if(input$group==TRUE) {
            p <- plot(plot.data.g) + facet_grid(.~input$UV)
        }
        p
    })
    
    #Creating the table
    output$tabelle <- renderDataTable({
        x <- av.select()
        dataset %>%
            count(!!as.symbol(x)) %>%
            mutate(Antwortkategorie=as_factor(!!as.symbol(x))) %>%
            mutate(n=n) %>%
            mutate(Prozent = prop.table(n)) %>%
            mutate('Kum. Prozent' = cumsum(Prozent)) %>%
            as.data.frame() -> for.table
        
        y <- input$UV
        
        test_tab <- table(x, y) %>% as.data.frame()
        
        if(input$group==FALSE){  
            datatable(for.table[,c(3,2,4,5)], extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(dom = 'Brtip', buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))) %>%
                formatPercentage(c('Prozent','Kum. Prozent'), 1) 
        }
        else if(input$group==TRUE){
            table(x, y)
            
        }
    })
    
    
}    

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had a couple of issues, so I rewrote some parts of it:

#### Data

I would suggest to provide an explicit `level` argument to `factor` to make sure that the subsequent plots and tables are in order (and not sorted alphabetically which would be the default). Secondly, your subsets selected almost always the entire level set so I removed them:

```r
set.seed(1) ## for reproducibility
levels.netusoft <- c("Sehr wenig", "Etwas", "Stark", "Sehr stark", "Verweigert", 
                     "Weiß nicht", "Keine Antwort")
levels.ppltrst <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", 
                    "Keine Antwort")
levels.polintr <- c("Überhaupt nicht", "Sehr wenig", "Etwas", "Stark", "Sehr stark", 
                    "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", "Keine Antwort")
levels.psppsgva <- c("Überhaupt nicht fähig", "Wenig fähig", "Ziemlich fähig", 
                     "Sehr fähig", "Vollkommen fähig", "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", 
                     "Keine Antwort")
levels.actrolga <- c("Wenig fähig", "Ziemlich fähig", "Sehr fähig", "Vollkommen fähig", 
                     "Verweigert", "Weiß nicht", "Keine Antwort")
levels.gndr <- c("männlich", "weiblich")

dataset <- data.frame("netusoft" = factor(sample(levels.netusoft, 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                                          levels.netusoft),
                      "ppltrst" = factor(sample(levels.ppltrst, 100, 
                                                replace = TRUE),
                                         levels.ppltrst),
                      "polintr" = factor(sample(levels.polintr, 100, 
                                                replace = TRUE),
                                         levels.polintr),
                      "psppsgva" = factor(sample(levels.psppsgva, 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                                          levels.psppsgva),
                      "actrolga" = factor(sample(levels.actrolga, 100, 
                                                 replace = TRUE),
                                          levels.actrolga),
                      "gndr" = factor(sample(levels.gndr, 100,
                                             replace = TRUE),
                                      levels.gndr),
                      check.names = FALSE)
```

#### Libs

I cleaned the list of needed libraries and added the needed `likert` library:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(likert)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(likert)
```

#### UI

Mostly unchanged, but a small thing to make your life easier and to save you some `ifs` later. Instead of using `conditionalPanel` for the question, I refered the conditional control to the server using an `uiOutput`/`renderUI` construct. In this way we can have one `input$question` which simply holds the proper question depending on the selection of the battery.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
   dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "European Social Survey Österreich Dashboard", 
                      titleWidth = 300),
      dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                       selectInput(inputId = "round", 
                                   label = "Wählen Sie eine ESS Runde aus",  
                                   c("ESS 1" = "1",
                                     "ESS 2" = "2",
                                     "ESS 3" = "3",
                                     "ESS 4" = "4",
                                     "ESS 5" = "5",
                                     "ESS 7" = "7",
                                     "ESS 8" = "8",
                                     "ESS 9" = "9"),
                                   selected = "9", selectize = FALSE), 
                       #end selectinput
                       conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "input.round == '9'",
                          selectInput(inputId = "battery", 
                                      label = "Wählen Sie Themenfeld aus",
                                      c("A: Medien-, Internetnutzung, Soziales Vertrauen" = "A",
                                        "B: Politische Variablen, Immigration" = "B"), 
                                      selectize = FALSE), #end selectinput
                          uiOutput("question_placeholder")
                       ),
                       checkboxInput(
                          inputId = "group",
                          label = "Daten gruppieren",
                          value = FALSE), #end checkbox
                       
                       conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "input.group == true",
                          selectInput(
                             inputId = "UV",
                             label = "Daten gruppieren nach:",
                             c("Geschlecht" = "gndr")
                          ) # end conditionalPanel
                       )
      ), # end dashboardSidebar
      dashboardBody(
         fluidRow(
            box(width = 7, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
                title = "Table:",
                dataTableOutput("tabelle", width = "100%")
            ),
            box(width = 8, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
                title = "Graph:",
                plotOutput("plot", width = "auto", height = 500)
            )
         ) # end fluidRow
         
      ) #end dashboardBody
   )
)
```

##### Server

Here I made some simplifications, explanations afterwards.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   get_data <- reactive({
      req(input$question)
      if (input$group) {
         dataset %>% 
            select(Antwortkategorie = input$question, req(input$UV)) %>% 
            group_by(grp = !!as.symbol(input$UV), Antwortkategorie)
      } else {
         dataset %>% 
            select(Antwortkategorie = input$question) %>% 
            group_by(Antwortkategorie)
      } 
   })
   
   
   output$question_placeholder <- renderUI({
      if (input$battery == "A") {
         choices <- c("A2|Häufigkeit Internetnutzung" = "netusoft",
                      "A4|Vertrauen in Mitmenschen" = "ppltrst")
      } else if (input$battery == "B") {
         choices <- c("B1|Interesse an Politik" = "polintr",
                      "B2|Politische Mitsprachemöglichkeit" = "psppsgva",
                      "B3|Fähigkeit politischen Engagements " = "actrolga")
      }
      selectInput(inputId = "question", 
                  label = "Wählen Sie eine Frage aus",
                  choices,
                  selectize = FALSE)
   })
   
   output$tabelle <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(get_data() %>% 
                   summarize(n = n()) %>% 
                   mutate(Prozent = n / sum(n),
                          "Kum. Prozent" = cumsum(Prozent)),
                rownames = FALSE) %>% 
         formatPercentage(c("Prozent","Kum. Prozent"), 1) 
   })
   
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      dat <- req(get_data())
      lik <- likert(dat %>% ungroup() %>% select(Antwortkategorie) %>% 
                       as.data.frame(),
                    grouping = if (input$group) dat %>% pull(grp))
      plot(lik)
   })
}
```

1. The reactive `get_data` returns the relevant columns from `dataset`. That is the proper question plus the grouping (if selected). It relies on `dplyr::group_by` to add the respective grouping layers. I group by `Antwortkategorie` as well, as I will use `summarise(n = n())` instead of `count(Antwortkategorie)` for finer control.
2. `renderUI`: based on the the selection of `battery` we add different choices to the `selectInput`. With this approach we can always refer to the question as `input$question` and no need of additional branching later.
3. `renderDataTable`: uses `get_data()` to receive the data which is already (thanks to the logic in `get_data`) accordingly grouped. All we have to do is to calculate counts using `n()` and percentages. You can see that if you select a grouping variable the table is updated accordingly. (percentages are always relativ to the grouping)
4. `renderPlot`: `likert` knows a parameter `grouping`, which, if not `NULL`, takes care of the grouping. Thus, all we have to do is to provide it to `likert`. There is a nuisance with `likert` that it can't deal with `tibbles`, hence, the explicit cast to `data.frame`. The `ungroup` is necessary becaus eby default `select` will always select the grouping elements on top of the explicitely selected ones.

Comment: Fantastic job! Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

@thothal Wow! Thank you very very much! I really appreciate your help!
Only one question: by selecting the group variable every Antwortkategorie is shown for "männlich" and "weiblich", e.g.:

| grp | Antwortkategorie | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| männlich | Sehr wenig | 11 |
| männlich | etwas | 5 |
| weiblich | Sehr wenig | 4 |
| weiblich | etwas | 3 |

How can I manage an output like this:

| Variable | männlich | weiblich |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sehr wenig | 11 | 4 |
| etwas | 5 | 3 |

Comment: @thothal
I´m afraid the table in my answer is shown incorrect

Comment: Fixed that for you (you needed to add another newline before the table)

Comment: And as for the request, that is just a simple `tidyr::pivot_wider` operation. Refer to `tidyr::pivot_wider` for an example of how to do that.